# Задача "модник" на C++

Tags: c++, алгоритм, олимпиада

прорешиваю олимпиады и наткнулся на такую задачу:

**Всего в одном месяце n дней. Вы знаете, что в этом месяце будет проходить m фэшн-эвентов. i-й фэшн-эвент будет проходить со дня li по день ri включительно. Во все дни i-го фэшн-эвента стоимость вашего наряда должна быть хотя бы xi. Конечно же нельзя носить одно и то же, поэтому каждый день, когда проходит хотя бы один фэшн-эвент, вы покупаете новый наряд. Заметьте, что в один день может быть несколько эвентов, но для них надо купить только один наряд. Сообщите минимальное суммарное количество денег, которое потребуется, чтобы удовлетворить условия всех фэшн-эвентов.**

*Пример ввода:*

10 3

1 5 5

6 10 6

3 7 7

*Пример вывода:*

63

У меня есть код, однако, проверочная система выдает вердикт "Wrong Answer".
Код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n,m;
    int total_price;
    int li,ri,xi;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector <int> month(n);
    for (int i=0; i<m;i++)
    {
        cin >> li >> ri >> xi;
        for (int q= li-1; q <= ri-1; q++)
        {
            if (month[q] < xi)
                month[q] = xi;
        }
            
            
    }
    for (int i=0; i<month.size();i++)
        total_price += month[i];
    cout << total_price;
    return 0;
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Есть ли более хороший способ решить задачу?

Comment: Вы уверены, что если вектор не инициализировать, он заполнится нулями? (Я не в курсе, просто бросилось в глаза)

Comment: Более хороший способ это все остальные способы, которые решают задачу, а ваш код не имеет ничего общего  с решением задачи. Только не спрашивайте как нужно решать...

Comment: Такие вопросы лучше всего сопровождать ссылкой на проверяющую систему...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev. Это проверяющая система Яндекс Контест. К сожалению, я не знаю, как можно воспользоваться ей, если сам не являешься участником соревнования.

Comment: @ARHovsepyan. Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить (хотя бы вкратце) что не так с моим кодом? Я знаю, что это вообще не показатель правильности решения, однако примеры тестов программа выполнила.

Comment: @zitraks mode,  не   знаю, может я не правильно понял условие задачи

Comment: Все же, какие ограничения на числа? Может, у вас просто переполнение (такое сплошь и рядом бывает)...

Comment: @HarryfromKiev. Вы имеете виду такие ограничения: В первой строке вводится два числа n и m (1 ≤ n ≤ 109, 1 ≤ m ≤ 105). Следующие m строк описывают фэшн-эвенты. В i-й строке записаны 3 числа li, ri и xi (1 ≤ li ≤ ri ≤ n, 1 ≤ xi ≤ 109) — даты фэшн-эвента и минимальная стоимость наряда?

Comment: total_price long long пробовали делать?   И что насчёт инициализации вектора? Стандарт гарантирует заполнение нулями? В остальном решение выглядит верным, но оно не пойдет по времени, O(n*m) - много для данных ограничений

Comment: Ну вот. Представьте себе сумму, скажем, пяти значений по 10^9 - какой тип нужен?..

Comment: @zitraks mode Ну что у вас получилось?

Comment: @MBo К сожалению, время доступа к проверочной системе вышло и я не успел проверить :( , однако, все равно спасибо за комментарии!